# OpenMP dynamic loop decomposition in chunks

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, partitioning

I am using OpenMP to go through a large loop in parallel. Let's say the array I'm working on has N entries in total. I would like one thread to do the first N/2 entries and the other thread the last N/2.

I have to avoid that the threads work on entries that are next to each other. The size N is always much bigger than the number of threads, so I don't need to worry about locks if I can get OpenMP to distribute the work the way I outlined above.

If the size N is known at compiletime, I can use `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,N/2)`. Unfortunately it isn't. So, how do I define the chunk size dynamically?

Comment: Can you clarify this part: "If the size N is known at runtime... Unfortunately it isn't".  If N isn't known at run time you can't use an `omp parallel for` at all for this.   If you can give some example code, perhaps we could figure out how to use tasks for this.

Comment: I've added the complete OpenMP clause to the question that I would use if N is just a static number.

Comment: Right, but that's not the issue; if N isn't known at _runtime_, you can't use a parallel for of any sort, leaving aside any scheduling issue.   I don't think any parallel library of any sort (intel TBB, cilk, etc) allows a parallel for when you don't know the loop limits at runtime.

Comment: chunk_size doesn't have to be known at compile time.  If it isn't a constant or a simple expression that the compiler can evaluate, then the chunk_size expression is evaluated at runtime.  So as long as N is known before you enter the loop, specifying (static, N/2) should work.  If you don't know the size of the array, then you either need to calculate it before the loop or you have to use tasking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use builtin openmp scheduling options as [@Jonathan Dursi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605620/openmp-dynamic-loop-decomposition-in-chunks/5606608#5606608) shows then you could implement required options yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
/* $ gcc -O3 -fopenmp -Wall *.c && ./a.out  */

static void doloop(int n) {
  int thread_num, num_threads, start, end, i;
#pragma omp parallel private(i,thread_num,num_threads,start,end)
  {
    thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
    num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    start = thread_num * n / num_threads;
    end = (thread_num + 1) * n / num_threads;

    for (i = start; i != end; ++i) {
      printf("%d %d\n", thread_num, i);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  omp_set_num_threads(2);
  doloop(10);
  return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
```

Comment: The nice thing about this answer is that it can be made to explicitly handle the case where N isn't evenly divided by the number of threads, or any other constraints you may have.

Answer (score 4):

There's no problem as long as N is known at runtime; I'm not sure why you think it has to be known at compile time.   OMP loop constructs would be of very limited use indeed if everything had to be known at compile time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;
    int chunksize;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s n, where n = number of iterations.\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n<1 || n>200) n = 10;

    chunksize = n/2;

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) default(none) shared(n,chunksize)
    {
        int nthread = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp for schedule(static,chunksize) 
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            printf("Iter %d being done by thread %d\n", i, nthread);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And it runs simply enough, as so:

```
$ gcc -v
[...]
gcc version 4.4.0 (GCC) 

$ gcc -o loop loop.c -fopenmp

$ ./loop 10
Iter 5 being done by thread 1
Iter 6 being done by thread 1
Iter 7 being done by thread 1
Iter 8 being done by thread 1
Iter 9 being done by thread 1
Iter 0 being done by thread 0
Iter 1 being done by thread 0
Iter 2 being done by thread 0
Iter 3 being done by thread 0
Iter 4 being done by thread 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on dotNET, and ended up writing a smart queue object that would return a dozen objects at a time, once they are available.  Once I have a package in hand, I'd decide on a thread that can process all of them in one go.

When working on this problem, I kept in mind that W-queues are better than M-queues.  It's better to have one long line with multiple workers, than to have a line for each worker.

Comment: It would be nice to avoid any unnecessary overhead, but maybe that's the only way...

Comment: There isn't much overhead due to memory, and algorithm is pretty straightforward.  If each node takes a considerable amount of time to process, then the costs are negligible.